# Delete the oldest files in folder if combined size of folder is more than 10G

Tags: linux, find, perl, rm

The following syntax will remove the files under `hive` folder:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/log/hive -type f -print -delete
```

I am trying to do the following:

Remove the oldest files under `/var/log/hive` only if folder size is more than **10G**

NOTE - the deletion process will stop when size under hive folder is exactly 10G , so purging process will start if size is more then 10G

Can we create this solution with find command or maybe another approach?

Comment: oldest in the sense?? can you specify number of days?

Comment: I mean the most oldest files , as ls -ltr will show the date and time of the files , and the removing will be from the oldest files according to ls -ltr info ( but I mentioned the ls -ltr only for example )

Comment: folder or file ??

Comment: its like you do du -sh .  (under hive folder ) , if size is more then 10G then need to triger the deletion files

Comment: need to delete only files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a GNU system, you could do something like:

```
cd /var/log/hive &&
  find . -type f -printf '%T@ %b :%p\0' |
    sort -zrn |
    gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
      BEGIN {max = 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024} # 10GiB; use max=10e9 for 10GB
      {du += 512 * $2}
      du > max {
        sub("[^:]*:", ""); print
      }' | xargs -r0 echo rm -f
```

That is sort the regular files by last modification time (from newest to oldest), then count their cumulative disk usage (here assuming there are no hard links) and delete every file when we've passed the 10GiB threshold.

Note that it doesn't take into account the size of the directory files themselves. It only considers the disk usage of regular files.

Remove `echo` when satisfied with the result.

On one line:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %b :%p\0' |sort -zrn|gawk -vRS='\0' -vORS='\0' '{du+=512*$2};du>10*(2^30){sub("[^:]*:","");print}'|xargs -r0 echo rm -f
```

To delete only *.wsp files when the cumulative disk usage of all regular files goes over 10GiB, you'd want to list the non-wsp files first. And at the same time, we can also account for the disk usage of directories and other non-regular files we were missing earlier:

```
cd /var/log/hive &&
  find . \( -type f -name '*.wsp' -printf WSP -o -printf OTHER \) \
     -printf ' %T@ %b :%p\0' |
    sort -zk 1,1 -k2,2rn |
    gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
      BEGIN {max = 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024} # 10 GiB
      {du += 512 * $3}
      du > max && $1 == "WSP" {
        sub("[^:]*:", ""); print
      }' | xargs -r0 echo rm -f
```

Comment: can I run it in one line ?

Comment: @yael, Sure, but why would you want to do that? All shells accept commands on several lines (though it can get awkwards with csh or tcsh).

Comment: because I want to run  it crom crontab -:)

Comment: @yael, OK. Though here, I'd rather create a script with that code and have the crontab run  that script. See edit for the one line version. You may want to test that it works OK first. I've not tested it myself.

Comment: lets say that we want to delete only the files that are ended with ".wsp" , can you please give update to show the second approach that delete only the .wsp deletion

Comment: we test your syntax , we create folder with 12G , and we run the syntax and after that we check the folder size , and folder size became 10G ( du -sh . ) , but can you please give a option how we can deleted only the ".wsp" files ?

Comment: not exactly , the concept will be the same , if total size of hive is more then 10G ( as du -sh . ) no matter which files , then it will be deleted only the oldest .wsp files  ,

Comment: I can open another question if you want ?

Comment: @yael, see edit

Comment: Great let me test this syntax , I will back soon with results ....

Comment: in case we want the size folder as 5G insted 10G , in that case we can change the du > 10 * (2^30) && $1 == "WSP"   TO   du > 5 * (2^30) && $1 == "WSP"   ?

Comment: first thank you so much , I see that you update the answer , so just to summary it in case for example we want to limit the folder to 5G , so we need to change the line as --> BEGIN {max = 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024} # 10 GiB   , am I right ?

Comment: I see that you made change  ,  why not do find /var/log/hive ? , why need to "cd /var/log/hive"  , if you can search by  find the logs under /var/log/hive

Comment: @yael, that would work too, but using `find .` means that file names will be shorter which reduces the amount of processing by all utilities. It can also reduce the number of `rm` commands that `xargs` need to run. It also avoid potential problems with `/var/log/hive` being renamed while the script is running. More  generally, as `find` can't accept arbitrary directory/file names as arguments, I got into the habit of using it with `.` wherever possible.

Comment: about my previous question "to start purge when total size 5G" , am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**Option 1:** To delete folder older than 90days and more than 10G

```
find /var/log/hive -size +10G -mtime +90 -type f -print -delete
```

**Option 2:** To delete the oldest folder

```
find /var/log/hive -size +10G -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2 | xargs rm
```

Comment: so both options will delete the files until size will be exactly 10G ?  ( in case size became for example 11.5G )

Comment: This deletes _files larger than 10Gb_.

Comment: I not want to delete files that are more then 10G  , what I mean is that --> in case of size under hive folder is more then 10G , only then the deletion mechanizem will work to delete the oldest files ,

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
while test "$(du -s /var/log/hive | cut -f1)" -gt 10000000 ; do rm -i /var/log/hive/"$(ls -t /var/log/hive | tail -1)" ; done
```

?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985

Comment: dose it stop to delete when size is 10G ?  ( what we need is to stop the deletion when size iz exactly 10G )   , I also update the question with note so it will be more clear

Comment: @yael: Yes, it stops if the size reaches 10GB or less (10GB, not 10GiB).

@Kusalananda: I took this from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242496/bash-script-to-remove-the-oldest-file-from-from-a-folder#242502. How to select the oldest file in a directory without parsing `ls`?